# PCA: understanding how to use loading vectors of X to recapture the geometry of X

Tags: pca, svd

If we suppose that `X` is an `n x d` matrix, and then perform PCA to obtain loading vectors `z_1, z_2, ... z_d`, why do we need to use all `d` loading vectors to exactly recapture the geometry of `X`?

My intuition is that without all the loading vectors, we would be "missing some information" from `X`... but I'm having trouble translating what "missing some information" means as a mathematically rigorous explanation.

Comment: One possible answer to the 1st paragraph is that PCA is just a particular case of orthogonal rotation. If you you have data points in d dimensions and you rotate the system of axes you loose no information about the data, relative positions of points. As for mathematical explanation of the "missing some information", I might you to read some top threads here about PCA.